# How to implement dynamic routing in next js?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, dynamic-routing

I have converted my React.js app to Next.js
Now i wanted to route to my blog details page on click of card on blog page
I am taking data from heroku api.
In react i was doing it using react-router-dom
How to do it in next.js ?

Comment: yes dynamic routing

Answer (score 0):

this page can help you to make your dynamic routing:
[Next Dynamic Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

Inside pages folder:

File and Directory are self routes concepts:

pages/test.js works for localhost:3000/test

pages/test1/test.js works for localhost:3000/test1/test

Similarly:

pages/post/[pid].js works for  localhost:3000/post/a OR localhost:3000/post/111 etc